# Formatting an idiomatically pronounceable time string

Tags: vb.net, string-formatting

I have programmed a form in Visual Basic which displays the current system time (hh:mm:ss) in a label called "DigitalTime".

Now for the hard part: **How do I program a second label ("WordTime") to use the current time (from "DigitalTime") and show it in the "WordTime" label in words like this:**

Example 1: (time is 22:50) I want label "WordTime" to show "10 minutes to 11".
Example 2: (time is 13:15) I want label "WordTime" to show "15 minutes past 1".

For the minutes 0-30 I want it to display "... minutes *past* ...". For the minutes 31-59 I want it to display "... minutes *to* ...".

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it isn't that hard thanks to the wonderful [ToString formatters available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for DateTime in .NET and using String.Format. The [DateTime structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in general has all you need to know on this stuff. One caveat and a gotcha, to subtract time from a current DateTime we Add negative amounts of time. There is no `SubtractMinutes` method on DateTime, only `AddMinutes`, so you add negative time.

With all that said something like this below. Ideally you'd just make it a function, but I left it fairly basic so it wouldn't get confusing.

**10 minutes to 11:**

```
Dim _textToMinute As String = String.Empty
If DateTime.Now().Minute > 30 Then
    _TextToMinute = "Past"
Else
    _textToMinute = "To"
End If


Dim _minutesTillNextHour = (DateTime.Now().AddHours(1).AddMinutes(-DateTime.Now().Minute) - dateTime.Now).Minutes
Dim _nextHour = DateTime.Now().AddHours(1).ToString("%h")
label1.Text = String.Format("{0} minutes {1} {2}", _minutesTillNextHour, _textToMinute, _nextHour)
```

**15 minutes past 1**

```
label1.Text = String.Format("{0} minutes {1} {2}", DateTime.Now().Minute, _textToMinute, DateTime.Now().ToString("%h"))
```

Comment: Alright, I have copied this code to the Form1_Load. But it is showing 2 Errors: 'Empty' is not declared. 'Empty' constant is no longer supported; use 'Nothing' instead. (But using 'Nothing' instead of 'Empty' just shows syntax error.   Error 2: 'String' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that i had a typo in there (actually a typo AND a code logic error, whoops!) I fixed both. My apologies!

Comment: I have removed the 'Empty' and 'String' from the code and it now shows Past and To correctly, but the numbers are not there??

Comment: Did you bind the results of String.Format to your labels as text? When you debug it are the proper values getting assigned to _nextHour and _minutesTillNextHour?

For what it's worth I debugged the entire thing in a test solution with a windows form and labels and it all worked fine.

Comment: I have added: 'Label1.Text = _textToMinute' underneath the code. But no luck. It only shows To and Past no numbers.

Comment: Right. What you need to do is add the results of the string.format to be assigned to your label. String.Format returns a String with the proper formatting you want. You need to send that to your Label1.Text. I updated my answer with a more explicit example assumign Label1.text is your label. If you need more help you should open another question (or just look) on how to assign the results of a variable or method to a label in Windows forms.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be working well, however, the label only shows the time in words as of when the application was launched and does not continue updating every minute. I was wondering if you could help me one more time. I understand you need a time? And what would the code be?

Answer (score 0):

When the minutes is 30,it is common practice to use the word "half", as in "half past 6".  Here's a simple little function that takes that into account and returns a formatted string that can be assigned wherever you need it:

```
Function TimeInCommonLang(ByVal input As DateTime) As String
    Dim minutes As String = ""
    Dim indicator As String = ""
    If input.Minute <= 30 Then
        indicator = "past"
        If input.Minute = 30 Then
            minutes = "half"
        Else
            minutes = input.Minute.ToString & " minutes"
        End If
    Else
        indicator = "to"
        minutes = (60 - input.Minute).ToString & " minutes"
        input = input.AddHours(1)
    End If
    Return String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", minutes, indicator, input.ToString("%h"))
End Function
```